# Is there any way to carry over background color between HTML documents?

Tags: javascript, html

My background color for my HTML page is white by default, and I have an option to set it to black via an anchor with no href attached to it. I also have another anchor with a link to another HTML page, however if the background color is black and you click the link to the second HTML page, the background color of the second page does not stay black. Is there a way to have the background color transfer over?

Here is the JavaScript function:

```
function changeBG(colour) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colour;
}
</script>
```

Here are the anchors to change the background color:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript: changeBG('white')">Light Theme</a>

<a href="#" onClick="javascript: changeBG('black')">Dark Theme</a>
</div>
```

Here is the anchor to go to the next HTML page:

`<a href="websitepage2.html">Next Page</a>`

Comment: You could use a cookie to store the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the browser's **localStorage** to save & retrieve the background colour.

To do this you need to modify the changeBG() function a little:

```
function changeBG(colour) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colour;
  localStorage.setItem('backColour', colour);
}
```

This will save the background colour into the localStarge, accessible using the variable backColour.

In your other html file you can do something like this

```
if (localStorage.getItem('backColour') != null) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('backColour');
}
```

So in case there is a value for backColour inside localStorage, use it as the background colour.